# modifiers within false conditions

Tags: conditional-statements, smarty, modifier

Sorry of this has been asked before, but I can't find it.
Why does the following fail with

> Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template
>   "/home/ezms/public_html_subs/dev4/design/backend/templates/index.tpl"
>   on line 31 "{""|foo }" unknown modifier "foo"

```
{if false} {""|foo} {/if}
```

I have certain code conditionally included I.e.

```
{if $x_enabled} {
  function foo() {
    return "hello";
  }
}
```

I would expect that if the smarty IF condition did not evaluate to true that the modifier would not be executed.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smarty is a compiler and uses a lexer to convert its code syntax into PHP. Then Smarty has PHP execute the code.

When compiling, it will fault on the unrecognized modifier. If the modifier was recognized, the lexer would convert that to a real function (based on what the plugin does) -- for example, foo(""). Being a modifier plugin, you are free to make the plugin do much more work deemed necessary, even if the result of any action on the argument is not used.

Then...
The compiled PHP code would be something like:

```
if(false){$smarty_user_functions->foo("");}
```

If the compile is successful, Smarty then has PHP execute that code, where PHP employs its own optimizing algorithms converting the human-readable script to token/opcode/bytecode. If when PHP runs this code, it will decide what to do on a false condition.

Comment: Seems more appropriate to fail at runtime...  But I get it.  Thanks for the feedback.  I changed things to do the modifier work in PHP and pass the results via variables rather than using a potentially undefined function as a modifier.

Comment: What language is your second code block? If pseudo-code, what is the intent?

Comment: All smarty.  Maybe I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: Lines 2-4 is not proper Smarty syntax. Lines 1 and 5 should be: `{if}...{/if}`.

Comment: sorry the second example is the declartion of the function foo() in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your `foo` modifier function in smarty plugin directory (https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.modifiers.tpl)
file would have a name *modifier.foo.php*
and contain code:

`function smarty_modifier_foo()
{
   return 'hello';
}`

then, your code `{if false} {""|foo} {/if}` in template will works.

Comment: Unfortunately this is an add-on product and I'm restricted to a certain directory structure.  Why is it executing if the condition is false?

Comment: `{if false} {""|foo} {/if}` this is example or your production code?